# Creating separate network with second router

Tags: networking, router

I have my NETGEAR R7000 (A) router directly connected to the ISP and with all my local devices; I also have a Pi-Hole and I have configured the router's A DNS to point to the pi-hole. All good.

The problem is that when I create a second Guest network, they are (of course) not being able to access the IP of the pi-hole because of client-isolation, and I don't want to setup the DNS manually for them everytime.

So, I just thought of connecting a spare old router (B) I have and create a secondary guest network using this.

I have tried to connect the router (B, flashed with DD-WRT) via WAN port to a LAN port of router (A).

First network is 10.0.0.0/24, while second guest is 192.168.1.0/24.

The router (B) actually got the IP address from A's DCHP, and it is abe to assign 192.168.1.X IP to new devices connected to it, but it doesn't let me navigate on Internet.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, is this network safe?